# Wrong integration by part of $\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-verification

If I have $\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx$ I can solve it by integration by parts, where $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]=e^x$, I have $\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx= 5x^2e^x+20e^x-10xe^x$: correct.

Why it doesn't works if I take  $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]=5x^2+10$?

I explain my doubt: $\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx= (\frac{5}{3}x^3+10x)e^x-\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx$, so $\int(5x^2+10)e^x dx= \frac{1}{2}(\frac{5}{3}x^3+10x)e^x$, but this is wrong. Why?

Thanks all.

Comment: Try it out, the power will keep increasing.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's just that you'll never finish. With the polynomial you can differentiate until it's constant, but the $e^x$ just sticks around. (By the way, as far as I can see there should be two steps in your calculation. I didn't check it to see if it's correct though.)

Comment: It's not. It should be $(5x^2+10)e^x-\int 10xe^xdx$. You should review the formulas.

Comment: I've tried it, but my question is: how a priori I have to choose a way to integrate?

Comment: @G.Cantisani You have to try things. If you try one thing and it seems like it's not going to work, try something else. There's no reasonable way to figure out what to try without trying anything most of the time.

Comment: I know I have to try, but I don't see why a right method leads to a wrong result.

Comment: @G.Cantisani As I said in an earlier comment, you never got the right result because you're doing it wrong. You left off an integration. Theoretically it gives the same answer both ways, except one way you never finish.

Answer (score 2):

There is technically a general method for approaching these integrals, but it's extremely complicated and not feasible for a human to use. Therefore in order to do these problems you can't just do anything you want and expect it to work out. It requires a correct approach.

For a real world example, say there's a wall in your way and you want to get to the other side. You could try to get through it by banging your head against the wall, but that pretty much never works. Generally the best approach is to go around it.

Comment: Nice comparison i must say!

Answer (score 0):

I check my attemp, and I find the error: integrating by part in second way, the correct result is: $\int (5x^2+10)e^x dx=(\frac{5}{3}x^3+10x)e^x-\int(\frac{5}{3}x^3+10x)e^x dx$; in this case -how someone noted- this integration by part never ends, because the degree of polynomial increases.